# Having a common SpringApplicationContextProvider to be used by all bean spring-managed and otherwise

Tags: java, spring

I have an ApplicationContextProvider class, which can used to access Spring ApplicationContext from beans not managed by Spring. Something like mentioned [here](http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2007/03/accessing-spring-beans-from-legacy-code.html)

For the spring managed beans however I can make them ApplicationContextAware, so they can get access to ApplicationContext.

My question is, is it a good idea to use the common ApplicationContextProvider to get spring application context from the spring-managed beans as well or should I continue to use ApplicationContextAware?

Answer (score 2):

Using a singleton with static reference to application context is asking for trouble. It is almost never a good idea to use such utility class in any case. When dealing with legacy web application use [`WebApplicationContextUtils`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html) instead.

I once reinvented this solution in a project during migration from EJB 2.1 to Spring - but after migration we get rid of it and could sleep again.

Back to your question - using such utility for Spring *managed* beans has no sense at all. To be honest, I rarely need `ApplicationContextAware` interface as well. Spring is suppose to inject dependencies, you shouldn't ask Spring for them all the time!

Can you show us some use case when you need quoted utility class (both for managed- and umanaged beans)? Looks like you are refusing to accept support Spring gives you.